# Not able to perform operation after running setup in coded-UI

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

My application(installer) starts but I am not able to perform any operation on the installer window. I have applied wait too. But, seems like that is not working. Can someone suggest that why it is not working. The code is as below:

```
public void runInstaller()
{
    #region Variable Declarations

    ApplicationUnderTest uIIDERASQLComplianceMaWindow = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(this.runInstallerParams.UIIDERASQLComplianceMaWindowExePath);
    while (!(uINextButton.WaitForControlExist() && uINextButton.WaitForControlReady()))
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    // Click 'Next' button
    Mouse.Click(uINextButton, new Point(42, 11));

    // Select 'I accept the Terms and Conditions of the' check box
    uIIaccepttheTermsandCoCheckBox.Checked = this.runInstallerParams.UIIaccepttheTermsandCoCheckBoxChecked;

    // Click 'Next' button
    Mouse.Click(uINextButton, new Point(23, 11));

    // Type 'abc' in 'txtDisplayName' text box
    uITxtDisplayNameEdit.Text = this.runInstallerParams.UITxtDisplayNameEditText;

    // Click 'Next' button
    Mouse.Click(uINextButton, new Point(42, 11));

    // Click 'OK' button
    Mouse.Click(uIOKButton, new Point(32, 13));

    // Click 'Cancel' button
    Mouse.Click(uICancelButton, new Point(39, 10));

    // Click 'Finish' button
    Mouse.Click(uIFinishButton, new Point(31, 12));
}
```

It is throwing an exception at line

```
 ApplicationUnderTest uIIDERASQLComplianceMaWindow = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(this.runInstallerParams.UIIDERASQLComplianceMaWindowExePath);
```

The exception is:

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToLaunchApplicationException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: "The application cannot be started. This could be due to one of the following reasons:
>   1) Another instance of the application is already running and only one instance can be running at a time.
>   2) The application started another process and has now stopped. You may need to launch the process directly.
>   3) You do not have sufficient privileges for this application." File: C:\Users\Wall2\Desktop\Install-64bit-v5.5.0.exe.

Comment: Have you tried to check if any of the possibilities that the exception lists is true? Do you have admin privileges? Is there a leftover instance of the application under test running?

Comment: I don't think that nothing of the exception really exists. Because, If I keeps the instance open by default and then tries to open the installer again, the code works.

Comment: To paraphrase your comment, if you manually start the installer and then run your code, everything works? That strengthens the suspicion that you lack privileges. Do you run VS as admin?